# Проблема с FREE KASSA

Tags: php, free-kassa

Значит захотел я подключить к сайту фри кассу. Кассу активировали все дела я вёл данные в настройках. Сохранил. Для проверки нажимаю кнопку оплатить, что в итоге меня перекидывает на чужую кассу. Написал в поддержку вот что ответили

1 - Проверьте что ваша ссылка на оплату начинается с pay.freekassa.ru/ Описание в документации: docs.freekassa.ru/#section/1.-Vvedenie/1.3.-Nastrojka-formy-oplaty 2 - В формировании ссылки на оплату участвует параметр currency ( Валюта платежа (RUB,USD,EUR,UAH,KZT) ) - это обязательный параметр! Описание в документации: docs.freekassa.ru/#section/1.-Vvedenie/1.3.-Nastrojka-formy-oplaty 3 - В формировании подписи так же участвует параметр currency - это обязательный параметр! Описание в документации: docs.freekassa.ru/#section/1.-...nie-podpisi-v-platezhnoj-forme

В скриптах я не разбираюсь от слова совсем прикреплю файл.(при покупке ссылка на оплату не начинается с pay.freekassa.ru так что мне нужна помощь с этим)

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$merchant_id = $fk_id;
$merchant_secret = $fk_secret_1;
 if(isset($_POST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID'])){
 function getIP() {
                        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
                        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                        }
                        if (!in_array(getIP(), array('136.243.38.147', '136.243.38.149', '136.243.38.150', '136.243.38.151', '136.243.38.189', '136.243.38.108'))) {
                        die("hacking attempt!");
                        }
getIP();

    $sign = md5($merchant_id.':'.$_REQUEST['AMOUNT'].':'.$merchant_secret.':'.$_REQUEST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID']);

    if ($sign != $_REQUEST['SIGN']) {
    die('wrong sign');
    }

$label = $_POST['intid'];
$idmoney = $_POST['MERCHANT_ORDER_ID'];
$data = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$yandex = '';
$suma = $_POST['AMOUNT'];
        if (is_numeric($idmoney))
        {
        $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$idmoney'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql_select);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row)
{   
$balance = $row['balance'];
}


$balancenew = $row['balance'] + $suma;
$update_sql1 = "Update users set balance='$balancenew' WHERE id='$idmoney'";
    mysqli_query($link,$update_sql1);
            $insert_sql1 = "
            INSERT INTO `payments` (`user_id`, `suma`, `data`, `qiwi`, `transaction`) 
            VALUES ('{$idmoney}', '{$suma}', '{$data}', '{$yandex}', '{$label}')
            ";
mysqli_query($link,$insert_sql1);
} 

    die('YES');
}
?>
```

Comment: Эт что за локализация? Или смесь с 1С-ом?

Comment: если вы про config.php то там просто данные хранятся основные по типу авторизации через вк

Comment: @АлександрКонев он про `если()`, `функция getIp()`, `умри()`, `ВСТАВИТЬ В` и тп.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это не тот скрипт. Чтобы мы могли вам помочь, укажите скрипт в котором вы принимаете данные заказа и отправляете человека на страницу оплаты (когда он выбрал метод оплаты фрикасса)

В этом скрипте (который вы нам показали) вы принимаете данные от фрикассы, записываете их в базу и пополняете пользователю баланс. Этот скрипт вызывается после того как человек оплатил заказ на фрикассе. Фрикасса или отправляет запрос на этот скрипт или редиректит пользователя на него